# Earth Engine: Splitting a feature into two using another geometry

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to split a feature into two based on a line geometry, but couldn't find any function to perform that operation. I have tried cutLines, intersection etc. but to no avail.

Here is my simple [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1be54c080454853c9bde63c9c7344842).