# Earth Engine: One sided buffer

Tags: google-earth-engine, buffer

How can one obtain one-sided buffer (left/right) of a line geometry in GEE? I haven't found any specific function to do that.

Comment: You could use turf.js library (https://turfjs.org/) for that, see an example of this kind of use with Leaflet: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344068/splitting-a-polygon-by-multiple-linestrings-leaflet-and-turf-js/344277#344277

Answer (score 1):

Great question.  What you are asking about is called an offset in the world of CAD. In CAD programs, a line can be offset: left, right or both. And a polygon object can be offset : inside, outside, or both.

In GIS, a buffer is a zone that is drawn around any point, line, or polygon that encompasses all of the area within a specified distance of the feature. This zone is drawn by a GIS in the form of a new polygon.[1] So-called 'Negative buffers' may also be used for polygons to specify a distance inward from the boundaries of the area feature.

Say there was a one-sided buffer.  Then how would that object interact with other geometric shapes?  Think about one-sided buffer in relation to the DE-9IM.

The Dimensionally Extended nine-Intersection Model (DE-9IM).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM

Did you try using the singleSide argument of the st_buffer() function?

```
g1 <- st_buffer(l1, .5, singleSide = TRUE) 
plot(g1)

g2 <- st_buffer(l1, .5, singleSide = FALSE) 
plot(g2)
```

As for the side of the offset, that gets me.

Comment: I somehow want to 'cut' a polygon into two polygons using a line (see my question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/368888/33177). 
That's why I was thinking to do one-sided buffer of the line and then perform intersection. I couldn't figure out a solution from your answer, can you please explain?

Comment: This looks like r code< not Google Earth Engine javascript.